# How to make hangouts forget your accounts password

Tags: google-hangouts

How to make hangouts forget your accounts password ? I don't want my friends to use my account since they are likely to stir up trouble so ....

Comment: Which Android version are you using? If it's Lollipop then you can use Guest/New user to get rid of your issue.

Comment: i think may be by clearing data it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. choose `Applications` (or applications manager)
3. swipe left/right to see all (installed) applications
4. click on `Hangouts` then `Clear all data`.

**Note:** This erases all data Hangouts had stored on your phone (just in case, you might want to do backup first).